# Need to incorporate Start time and end time against each steps in my Automated script

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I want to incorporate start time and end time against each steps in my automated scripts. I am using selenium with java & test NG

```
strCurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormat(driverProperties.getProperty("logFolderDateFormat")).format(date);
extent = new ExtentReports("./"+driverProperties.getProperty("BatchFileName")+strCurrentDate+".html", false);
extent.loadConfig(new File("./extent-config.xml"));
extent.addSystemInfo("Cockpit Build No.", driverProperties.get("BuildNumber").toString());
```

Comment: Why do you need time after each step? Are you sure you didn't mean to say tests?

Answer (score 0):

There is following way to achieve this:

1) The first way by using StopWatch:

```
 StopWatch pageLoad = new StopWatch();
 pageLoad.start();

  //Open your webpage and Perform Tesst

 pageLoad.stop();
 //Get the time
 long pageLoadTime_Seconds = pageLoad.getTime() / 1000;
 System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: " + pageLoadTime_Seconds + " seconds");
```

2) Second way by using Javascript executor:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
// Now calculate the page load time
double pageLoadTime_Seconds = (Double) jse.executeScript("return (window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000");
System.out.println("Total Page Load Time: "+ pageLoadTime_Seconds + " seconds");
```

3) You can use TestNG listener:

```
 public class ListenerTest implements ITestListener                     
    {       

        @Override       
        public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {                   
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        }       

        @Override       
        public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {                    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        }
}
```

4) Also, you can use **@BeforeMethod** and **@AfterMethod** to calculate the start and the end time of the method.